# IOException: Stream closed using with-open

Tags: file-io, clojure

For some reason, compiling and running this function (in CIDER) will result in the following error:

```
1. Unhandled java.io.IOException
   Stream closed
```

---

```
(defn file-lines
  [path]
  (with-open [file-reader (clojure.java.io/reader path)]
    (line-seq file-reader)))
(file-lines "test")
```

Example file `test`:

```
one
two
three
```

Obviously, the expected result is something along the lines of `("one" "two" "three")`.

Comment: @zerkms Ooh, didn't think about that. Still new to Clojure, but that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @downvoter the underlying principle of this question is not obvious. It hardly would count as lacking in research effort. Remember the person, please. Duplicates shouldn't be automatically downvoted; I shouldn't be penalized for misunderstanding the source of the problem. (And perhaps I should mention that you shouldn't penalize someone for providing a simple example demonstrating the problem; this should rather be encouraged.)

Comment: Upvoted (since I agree with you). The question is well asked and nothing is wrong with it.